# Import multiple data from webpage into Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a stocks sheet with lots of stock items. Each stock has multiple data and I'm scraping this data from multiple websites.

Currently, as my sheet is always increasing, I'm starting to have troubles to do `IMPORTXML` and `IMPORTHTML` functions.

Question: It would be possible to import, let's say, an entire webpage's source into a cell just once, and then I could run my `IMPORTHTML`/`IMPORTXML` **having that cell as a source?** I'm thinking about it because in this case I just have to call that particular page once and just process all different data inside the sheet itself.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Apps Script instead of a built-in formula.

The above because there is no built-in function that imports the data "as-is"

- IMPORTDATA will split the source code by commas and break lines
- IMPORTXML doesn't import tags, only the text that they enclose.
- IMPORTHTML only the content of import tables and lists

By the other hand the above functions can't be used to parse data from cells, the only are able to parse content from external sources referred by mean of a URL.

---

Regarding the use of Google Apps Script it has the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 0):

to import source code you can use `IMPORTDATA` formula. depends on your website structure you may need to ArrayConstrain it:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("url-here"), 5000, 25)
```